# How to determine if a memory address references a valid file offset

Tags: reverse-engineering, offset

I am trying figure out a way to calculate if a given address or list of addresses correspond to a valid file offset. I know to calculate an offset for a valid address  uses the formula:

ByteVirutalAddress - (ImageBase + SectionRelativeVirtualAddress) + PointerToRawdata = ByteOffset

I use this formula when patching instructions using a manual hex editor method as opposed to a nice easy to use GUI like Immunity.

What I am trying to do is find out weather an address or list of addresses correspond to a file offset. For example:

Section name - Address - Size

Image base: 00400000 - 00001000
.text: 00401000 - 00003000
.rdata: 00404000 - 00001000
.data: 00405000 - 0002B000

How do I calculate if addresses 00404185 or 0042F300 relate to a valid file offset or not?

My logic for this is:

you would need to do PointerToRawData + SizeOfRawdata + IMagebase, 400000 in this case. And do this for each section.

OR

Would it be correct to add Virtual Address of the section to the SizeOfRawdata of the section. From the result you should be able to see if either of these 2 addresses correspond to a valid file offset.

From the results, see which of the 2 above addresses are referenced in the result, i.e. result = 42D100. this references 0042300 however does not reference or correspond to 00403185.

Please let me know if my logic is flawed.

I have looked around a lot and have not found an information for this kind of calculation specifically. It is only useful if checking for correct alignment or possible corruption. I know that there are tools out there to do it for you but I like to know how to do things manually rather than rely on a script or tool. It helps when things go wrong with tools and scripts.

Answer (score 0):

just so this can be answered. I have figured out the correct logic for figuring this one out.

It would be correct to use the second option,  + < Section SizeOfRawdata> = Maximum possible RVA range for that section. This should give you the maximum possible relative virtual address of that section and then from this, you can see if the address either falls within this value or not.